# Naming of the belongs on or to?

Tags: discussion

I'm not a native English speaker, but whenever I see the label "Belongs on ..." makes me feel it should be "Belongs to ..." somehow? Can someone explain the wording?

Comment: interesting questions... one of those things that comes naturally to a native speaker, but most of us can't really come up with the reason why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word "belongs" can be used in a broader sense, without "to".  For example, "the suitcase belongs on top of the wardrobe".  Since you would say a post was "on superuser", it's correct to say "belongs on superuser" in that context.

Comment: It's kinda ironic I think, as when the question gets moved to the appropriate site, it belongs to that site from then.

Comment: The sites are locations, not entities. Even after it is moved it belongs 'on' that site as the sites aren't possessive.

Answer (score 3):

Belongs on refers to a place to where it has to be kept?

Belongs to refers to a person that owns it?

Answer (score 3):

It might also help you to review [the definition of "site"](http://www.answers.com/site):

> *n.*
>
> 1. The place where a structure or group of structures was, is, or is to be located: a good site for the school.
> 2. The place or setting of something: a historic site; a job site.
> 3. A website.

Note that 1 and 2 refer to a location in the physical world, while 3 builds on these to establish a metaphor: a page or set of pages on a given host can be thought of as similar to to structures on a particular piece of ground.

So if a question is a structure (say... a bike shed), then it belongs on a piece of ground *somewhere* - and the close reasons establish that it was originally constructed on the wrong site.